# java printing nothing instead of 0

Tags: java, formatting, int

```
   // Binomial Expansions
        String the_x, the_y;
        System.out.println("Binomial Expansions:");
        for(int i=0; i<=max; i++){
            num = 1;
            r = i+1;
            xpow=i;
            ypow=0;
            System.out.print("(x + y)^"+i+" = ");
            if(i==0) System.out.print("1");
            for(int j=0; j<=i; j++){
                if(j>0){
                num = num*(r-j)/j;
                System.out.print("x^"+(xpow+1)+" + ");
                System.out.print(num+"x^"+xpow+"y^"+ypow);
                }
                xpow--;
                ypow++; 
            }
            System.out.println();
        } // End of binomial expansions
```

I have few questions regarding my code.

1. How can I not print 0 and 1? and is there any recommended way to get rid `^` when its power is 0 or 1?
2. The reason I am printing `x` twice is that I want to x is located before y, like this `(x + y)^5 = x^5 + 5x^4y + 10x^3y^2 + 10x^2y^3 + 5xy^4 + y^5` However, if I don't print x twice, my result looks like this `(x + y)^5 = x^5 + 5y^1x^4 + 10y^2x^3 + 10y^3x^2 + 5y^4x^1 + 1y^5`. What can I do with?
3. I think my title and tags are not appropriate, what kind of trouble I am having that I can search later?

What I looked are `DecimalFormat` and `TypeCast` but I don't think both are not applicable this situation. Thanks in advance

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but why not just use an if statement to check for 0 or 1 and for that case have a different printing line?

Comment: I thought about that too. I was curious there are other way to do it.  #2 is big problem to me

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
static String power(String v, int p) {
    switch (p) {
    case 0: return "1";
    case 1: return v;
    default: return v + "^" + p;
    }
}

static String mult(int k, String... terms) {
    if (k == 0)
        return "0";
    String r = "" + k;
    for (String t : terms) {
        if (t.equals("0"))
            return "0";
        else if (t.equals("1"))
            continue;
        else if (r.equals("1"))
            r = t;
        else
            r += t;
    }
    return r;
}

static void biominal(int max) {
    System.out.println("Binomial Expansions:");
    for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
        int num = 1;
        int r = i + 1;
        System.out.print("(x + y)^" + i + " = ");
        System.out.print(power("x", i));
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            num = num * (r - j) / j;
            System.out.print(" + " + mult(num, power("x", i - j), power("y", j)));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

and

```
biominal(5);
```

result:

```
Binomial Expansions:
(x + y)^0 = 1
(x + y)^1 = x + y
(x + y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2
(x + y)^3 = x^3 + 3x^2y + 3xy^2 + y^3
(x + y)^4 = x^4 + 4x^3y + 6x^2y^2 + 4xy^3 + y^4
(x + y)^5 = x^5 + 5x^4y + 10x^3y^2 + 10x^2y^3 + 5xy^4 + y^5
```